# Translate English expression "exactly four" in ALCQO description logic

Tags: description-logic

I have to translate in ALCQO the following sentence:

*A square is a polygon with exactly four edges and exactly four vertices which are line segments.*

I have tried the following approach using ALCQO:

```
Square ≡ Polygon ⊓ (≥4hasPart.Edges) ⊓ (≤4hasPart.Edges) ⊓ (≥4hasVertices.LineSegments) ⊓
 (≤4hasVertices.LineSegments)
```

I am not sure about the following two cases:

1. Using `≥` and `≤` in the same sentence I am actually achieving to translate the phrase "*exactly one*".
2. `hasVertices.LineSegments` I am actually achieving to translate the phrase "*vertices which are line segments*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, using `≥` and `≤` in the same sentence translates to `exactly`. I have written about this on my blog [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2019/02/23/understanding-owl-min-vs-max-vs-exactly-property-restrictions/).
2. If you have `≥4hasVertices` or `≥4hasVertices.Top` it means the filler of `hasVertices` can be any concept from your domain. When you have `≥4hasVertices.LineSegment` the filler of `hasVertices` can only be `LineSegments`.